# SQL Rounding and Selecting

Tags: sql, select, decimal, rounding

I want to be able to see if a number is rounded to .0 then just set it to a whole number

For example if something rounds to 10.0 then I just want to set it to 10.

I cant seem to find a way to select the last number after the decimal point in order to set it to the whole number?

Is there a function that can do this for decimal numbers?

Comment: can you subtract the whole number portion and see if it's zero?

Comment: Are you wanting to change its type? (from decimal to int?) Otherwise, 10.0 == 10.

Comment: `where floor(f)=ceiling(f)`

Comment: Please tag your question (or post it here and we'll do it for you) On what your DBMS is (mysql, sql server, oracle...) and are you doing an update on records, or just looking to select the integer values.

Comment: Also worth noting that in a typed set of decimals `10` would likely always include trailing zeros as per its scale so you would need to cast to a character type or convert in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

To do them all

```
 UPDATE MyTable SET value1 = ROUND(Value1,0)
```

To just do the ones that need it

```
 UPDATE MyTable SET value1 = ROUND(Value1,0) WHERE Value1 - cast(Value1 as int) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that you are using SQL Server, I believe you are looking for the `FLOAT` data type.

There is an unanswered question here: are you trying to store this value, or are you trying to return this value?  If you are trying to store it, you need to change the data type of the storage location, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn FLOAT
```

If you are trying to retrieve it, you can use a `CAST()` statement, like this:

```
SELECT CAST(MyColumn AS FLOAT) AS MyConvertedColumn
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the below may be use full for you. Verify by changing float value like (3.178, 3.568, 3.789....)

```
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @f FLOAT
SET @f = 3.789

SET @i = cast(@f AS INT)
SELECT @i

SET @i = ROUND(@f, 0)
SELECT @i

SET @i = FLOOR(@f)
SELECT @i

SET @i = CEILING(@f)
SELECT @i
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @A float

SELECT @A=10.03

SELECT ROUND(@A,1,0)